# What is best way to store huge Cities for auto complete query?

Tags: sql, amazon-s3, indexing

I have list of cities, around 2712406 records. Each has state code and user first selects state code.

**Both StateCode and Name are already indexed.**

My current query to Database hits in the form of `/cities?code=[StateCode]&name=[Alphabets]`

Which internally translate to

```
return db.Cities.Where(x=>x.StateCode == stateCode && x.Name.StartsWith(name))
                .OrderBy( x=> x.Name )
                .Take(10);
```

This query times out sometime when database is busy for little bigger actions.

I have thought of two ways,

1. Storing pre configured queries on amazon S3.
2. Combining StateCode and Name as one Column and do SearchName.StartWith(stateCode +"/" + name)

**Storing S3 Objects**

I calculated total number of combinations that user need is 10 million. So assuming 5KB of JSON for only retrieving first 10 cities. It needs 50GB of storage. Roughly coming around $5 per month. Which is good but if I store my json as `/stateCode/a /stateCode/b` etc will serve faster to user with CDN?

**Combining State and City Key**

Let's say I have a separate column combined and index as "StateCode/Name". 
Here I know that query will hit B+ Tree of index. Will lookup on one column index will have greater benefit or will it be almost same as current query and I am better off with S3. I don't know whether S3 will give same performance as DB, all I can do is setup multiple readonly DB in my each app server.

Comment: @dasblinkenlight of course yes, I just updated the code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turned out that combined TEXT INDEX worked well. Joins are expensive operation.

1. Create Column CityPath = StateCode + '/' + CityName
2. Index CityPath

Query performs better then AND of two different result sets.

```
@CityPath = StateCode + '/' + CharactersTyped + '%'
SELECT TOP 10 * FROM Cities WHERE CityPath LIKE @CityPath
```

In the above query B+ index has to search limited sub-tree as StateCode is itself the root. However in the following query, B+ index has to search larger sub-tree and each result has to be compared for StateCode equivalency. The resultset of B+ index scan for CityName search is larger in this second query, which leads to microsecond timeouts.

```
@StateCode = StateCode
@CityName = CharactersTyped    
SELECT TOP 10 * FROM Cities WHERE CityName LIKE @CityName
     AND StateCode = @StateCode
```

Computed Column Indexes can improve searching of data if data exists in hierarchy as shown above.

Comment: Just for curioslty: are you sure you have used a single index on both columns (statecode, cityname) in this order for your test?

Comment: Well, then it should perform more or less equally to your solution. However, you are happy with the computed column, why not.

Comment: It did timeout with index on both columns as well. Computed column so far did not timeout.

Answer (score 1):

Regarding combining State and City Key in a SQL DB: You can also use a B+Tree index if you leave the columns separated. You'd just need to use a [combined|concatenated|multi-column] index. E.g.

```
CREATE INDEX blah ON cities (statecode, name);
```

Note: one index containing both columns. The column that is used with a non-exact operator (`StartWith` instead of equals) goes last.

This index supports your query if the StartWith method translates to SQL like:

```
SELECT name
  FROM cities
 WHERE state = ?
   AND name LIKE 'b%'
```

If `StartsWith` is implemented in another way, you might need to fiddle to get a proper response time. Best is to switch on SQL query logging and have a look. It is perfectly possible that your ORM tool translates `StartsWith` to something that cannot use this index properly, but it is probably easy to work around so that it works well (and fast).

ps: you are using "take(10)" without giving an ORDER BY (sql) which yields undefined results.

pps.: I find the S3 idea interesting too ;)

Comment: I have already indexed both columns. I have updated my question. I am also doing OrderBy, I just wrote the code for example, but actual query does have OrderBy and Take both.

Comment: @AkashKava So what question remains from your side? The index SHOULD be used (if you have *one* index on *both* column as shown above, also in the order as shown above) and it will probably be fast enough. If it isn't used, log the SQL query and show it to us.

Comment: Both indexes are used in query plan, question is single index will perform better over S3?

Comment: @AkashKava A single index will definitively perform better than two—probably by an order of magnitude! And probably good enough. Comparing to the S3 idea is hard however. Keep in mind that S3 will also need some kind of index that might look very similar to the one I suggested above.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I solved this by creating a computed column and index on it.